# F# dynamic object access

Tags: c#, .net, f#, dynamic-language-runtime

Is there a way to access DLR object (eg. DynamicObject subclass instance) members (properties and methods) in F# that is similar to C# dynamic ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a module now on nuget that uses the dlr to implement the dynamic operator. [FSharp.Interop.Dynamic](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Interop.Dynamic/)

It has several advantages over a lot of the snippets out there.

- Performance it uses [Dynamitey](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey/wiki/UsageReallyLateBinding) for the dlr call which implements caching and is a PCL library
- Handles methods that return void, you'll get a binding exception if you don't discard results of those.
- The dlr handles the case of calling a delegate return by a function automatically, this will also allow you to do the same with an FSharpFunc
- Adds an !? prefix operator to handle invoking directly dynamic objects and functions you don't have the type at runtime.

  It's open source, Apache license, you can look at the [implementation](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Interop.Dynamic/blob/master/FSharp.Dynamic/Dynamic.fs) and the basic unit test [example cases](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Interop.Dynamic/blob/master/Tests/Library1.fs).

Answer (score 9):

As eriawan mentioned, the `?` operator behaves a bit like the `dynamic` type in C#. The article about calling SQL doesn't rely on anything from the DLR, because you can provide your own implementation of the `?` operator and the compiler uses it directly.

I also wrote a brief example of how to use the `?` operator to call members using DLR, which is [available on F# snippets](http://fssnip.net/2U) and there is a more [sophisticated version by Matthew Podwysocki](http://codebetter.com/matthewpodwysocki/2010/02/10/f-and-the-dynamic-lookup-operator-ala-c/). Another snippet shows how to use it to call standard [.NET types using Reflection](http://fssnip.net/2V).

See also:

- [Looking for robust, general op_Dynamic implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057672/looking-for-robust-general-op-dynamic-implementation)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is. You can use `?` operator in F#, and it will perform the same way in dynamic typing in C# and VB.NET in .NET 4.0. For a start, you can read this sample Dynamic SQLDataReader from Tomas Petricek's blog:

http://tomasp.net/blog/dynamic-sql.aspx

Here's a quote from his article:

> In this article, we'll look how to use
>   the dynamic operator to make the
>   experience of using ADO.NET from F#
>   dramatically better. Dynamic operator
>   (there are actually two of them) are a
>   simple way of supporting dynamic
>   invoke in F#. We can use it to write
>   code that looks almost like an
>   ordinary method call or property
>   access, but is resolved dynamically at
>   runtime (using the name of the method
>   or property). The following example
>   shows what we'll be able to write at
>   the end of this article:
>
> ```
> // Call 'GetProducts' procedure with 'CategoryID' set to 1
> use conn = new DynamicSqlConnection(connectionString)
> use cmd = conn?GetProducts
> cmd?CategoryID <- 1
> conn.Open()
>
> // Read all products and print their names
> use reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
> while reader.Read() do
>   printfn "Product: %s" reader?ProductName
> ```
>
> If you ever tried to call a SQL stored
>   procedure directly using the
>   SqlCommand, then you can surely
>   appreciate the elegance of this code
>   snippet. Let's now take a look at a
>   larger example and some of the neat
>   tricks that make this possible...

And for more info, you can read the rest of his article.
Happy dynamic coding in F# :)

Comment: tnx. strange how Google didn't turn up with that link on F# dlr/dynamic dispatch :\ 
my google-fu sucks

Comment: You're welcome. you're right, it didn't show up in the google query.

Comment: Actually ? in F# is not nearly the same as dynamic in C# and Tomas' stored procedure example doesn't use the DLR. See Tomas' answer and the other linked question.

Comment: Well once I found the ? I pretty much figured out how to do the DLR specific stuff but I agree his answer is more correct sry. eriawan :)