# Dapper dot net query in F#

Tags: f#, dapper

I'm trying to use Dapper dot net in F# to perform a simple SQLite query.
Dapper returns a collection of dynamic objects: using them in C# is straightforward, but from what I understood F# has no dynamic property lookup implementation out-of-the-box.

This is working but I suppose there are better ways to do this without resorting to reflection:

```
let (?) x prop =
    let flags = BindingFlags.GetProperty ||| BindingFlags.InvokeMethod
    x.GetType().InvokeMember(prop, flags, null, x, [||])

let doQuery () =
    //...
    let conn = new SQLiteConnection (connString)
    conn.Open ()

    conn.Query("select first_name from customers")
        |> Seq.map (fun c -> c ? first_name)
        |> List.ofSeq
```

What is the best way to implement the ? operator in this case?

Comment: It seems that this thread answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150087/f-dynamic-object-access

Comment: @pad Good answer.  You should have added your response as an answer so I could upvote it :-)

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci: I add it as an answer, not sure that it is worth an answer:).

Comment: Nit: use `c?first_name` (no spaces) to be idiomatic.  `?` is like `.` here.

Comment: Not a solution, but have you considered using FsSql (https://github.com/mausch/FsSql) instead? It's written specifically for F#.

Comment: Or SOMA http://soma.codeplex.com/

Comment: I am accessing an existing db so I have no choice, but I'll keep FsSql and SOMA in mind for future needs!

Comment: @FrancescoDeVittori : FsSql doesn't need a specific database schema, the main point of it is simply making ADO.NET more palatable from F#.

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer: oh sorry hadn't realized that. Switching to FsSql immediately!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150087/f-dynamic-object-access) consists of several solutions for your problem. Especially, [FSharp.Interop.Dynamic](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Interop.Dynamic/) is available on NuGet and ready to use.

Comment: I was hoping there was an easier way (or without an external library). I suppose great power/great responsibility etc... :-)

Answer (score 3):

When using Dapper with F#, you can specify your query parameters using [F# Anonymous Records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/anonymous-records) and map the results directly to an F# Record, like so:

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type CustomerDto = 
    {
        FirstName: string
    }

let selectSql = "select first_name as FirstName from customers where first_name = @firstName"

conn.Query<CustomerDto>(selectSql, {|firstName = "Francesco"|})
```

Note that F# Anonymous Records were introduced in [F# 4.6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/whats-new/fsharp-46#anonymous-records).