# Parametric LINQ query

Tags: linq, f#, quotations

This is another take on [accessing dynamic objects in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36539639/accessing-dynamic-objects-in-f) There I'm using `let y = x.Where(fun x -> x.City ="London").Select("new(City,Zip)")` to parametrize the query and extract the necessary items. These would correspond to columns in an SQL query, and be represented by a property of the datacontext. This is the part that I would like to pass in as a parameter.

```
type Northwind = ODataService<"http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc">
let db = Northwind.GetDataContext()
let query2 = query { for customer in db.Customers do
                     select customer}  |> Seq.toArray
let qryfun (x:Northwind.ServiceTypes.Customer) =
    query { for x in query2 do
            select (x.City,x.CompanyName,x.Country)}
```

Basically I would like to pass in not only `x` but also `x.*`. As I'm accessing one database that is fixed, I can factor out x. However I  now have 40 small functions extracting the different columns. Is it possible to factor it out to one function and pass the property as an argument? So sometimes I extract`x.City` but other times `x.Country`. I have tried using quotations however cannot splice it properly and maybe that is not the right approach.

Comment: I think you can just return tuple from the query like `select (customer, customer.City)` and your `qryfun` will accept tuple as a parameter

Since all variety of customer properties dont have static type, you either use tuples for intermediate data flow between functions/transformations or define your own record type and map it in your query

Comment: @paulik thx. I'm not sure that is doable. E.g.  `let qryfun (x, x.column) = query { for x in query2 do
            select (x.column)}` where x is the DB table (Northwind.ServiceTypes.Customer) and x.column is a Column (or field) in the Customer table, it could be x.City, x.Country, etc.... then I would call `qryfun (Northwind.ServiceTypes.Customer, Northwind.ServiceTypes.Customer.City)` The 2nd argument is tricky because Northwind.ServiceTypes.Customer.City belongs to each record not to the table. If you take a look at the referenced question, I bult it from a string ("new(City, Country)")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding quotation splicing, this works for me:

```
open System.Linq

type record = { x:int; y:string }

let mkQuery q =
    query {
        for x in [{x=1;y="test"}].AsQueryable() do
        select ((%q) x)
    }

mkQuery <@ fun r -> r.x, r.y @>
|> Seq.iter (printfn "%A")
```