# C#'s 'dynamic' in F#

Tags: dynamic, f#, dynamic-language-runtime

One example of using the DLR in C# is as follows:

```cs
dynamic dyn = new MyObject();
dyn.MyMethod(); //resolved at runtime
```

what would be the equivalent in F#?

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `?` operator has similar expressive power to the `dynamic` keyword in C# (but it can be only used for reading of properties, method invocation and setting of properties).

There is no built-in implementation that would allow you to dynamically use properties or methods of a .NET class (via Reflection or DLR), but there are some fairly solid implementations from the community. This has been discussed in [another SO question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057672/looking-for-robust-general-op-dynamic-implementation).

There are also implementations of `?` that allow you access some common data sources such as SQL databases. For example, [this MSDN article includes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh304373.aspx) a definition that allows you to write `db?Query?Foo(1)` to call a stored procedure named `Foo`.

For various other types (such as finding an element in XAML or accessing elements or attributes in XML document), the definition of `?` is quite easy to write.

Answer (score 9):

On the flip side, if you're trying to expose `dynamic` behavior to C# from F#, you can use [`DynamicAttribute`<sup>[MSDN]</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287751.aspx). For example, declaring a dynamic property might look like

```
type HasDynamicProperty() =
    [<Dynamic([|true|])>]
    member this.DynamicObject : obj = ...
```

which is used from C# like

```
var hdp = new HasDynamicProperty();
dynamic dynObj = hdp.DynamicObject;
```

Answer (score 9):

There's a package called [`FSharp.Interop.Dynamic`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Interop.Dynamic/) and that will make it possible to do a call to a dynamic object using the `?` operator.

Answer (score 4):

F# has the ? operator which you use like so:

```
 myVariable?SomePropertyThatIsNotDeclared
```

There is no dynamic keyword equivalent. Take a look at this article for how to use it https://weblogs.asp.net/podwysocki/using-and-abusing-the-f-dynamic-lookup-operator

Comment: When trying to use ? operator, I get the following error: "error FS0043: Method or object constructor 'op_Dynamic' not found". Any ideas :) ?

Comment: So, the bottom line is that "?" operator is much more versatile than just "dynamic" keyword. But the downside is that the real functionality should be provided by the user (e.g. if I need to make use of the DLR, I'd have to code all the CallSite<T> stuff manually). Are there any out-of-the-box implementations of "?" in F# libs?

Comment: Article now returns a 404

Comment: @Kurren the link has been replaced