# Set a property on ViewBag dynamic object in F#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, f#, razor

I have this action method in C#:

```
  public ActionResult Index() {
      ViewBag.Message = "Hello";
      return View();
  }
```

And this view (Index.cshtml):

```
  <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
```

And this produces the expected "Hello" on the page.

I want to do the controller in F#. I've tried

```
type MainController() =
  inherit Controller()
  member x.Index() =
    x.ViewBag?Message <- "Hello"
    x.View()
```

And this produces the error message "Method or object constructor 'op_DynamicAssignment' not found".

I've looked at some of the F# code samples for the dynamic operator, and I can't see anything that's shorter than several pages of description and many lines of code. They seem to be too general for just this property "setter".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `ViewBag` property is just a wrapper that exposes the `ViewData` collection as a property of type `dynamic`, so that it can be accessed dynamically from C# (using property set syntax). You could use implementation of `?` based on DLR to do that (see [this discussion at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057672/looking-for-robust-general-op-dynamic-implementation)), but it is easier to define `?` operator that adds data directly to `ViewDataDictionary` (which is exposed by the `ViewData` property):

```
let (?<-) (viewData:ViewDataDictionary) (name:string) (value:'T) =
  viewData.Add(name, box value)
```

Then you should be able to write

```
x.ViewData?Message <- "Hello"
```

Comment: #Tomas Giving credit where it's due, I used your F# Empty Web Template, described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh304375.aspx, to generate this code in just a minute (but the problem did arise in a real project).

Comment: I needed to provide it for TempData as well, so changed the first paramater to `(dictionary:IDictionary<string,obj>)`

Comment: Could you elaborate on how F# knows where to split the operator? It seems weird to have `(?<-)`, and using it as `x.y?z <- q`

Comment: It is not a general features - the F# compiler treats `?<-` in a special way - and there is no way for defining similar operators on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
x?ViewBag <- "Hello"
```

Try:

```
x.ViewBag?Message  <- "Hello"
```

Comment: Thankyou. I've done that but it still produces "Method or object constructor 'op_DynamicAssignment' not found". I've edited that question to include this suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide a similar example, the [MvcMovie example in the ASP.NET Core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-view?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio-code#passing-data-from-the-controller-to-the-view) uses the following controller method:

```
public IActionResult Welcome(string name, int numTimes = 1)
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Hello " + name;
    ViewData["NumTimes"] = numTimes;

    return View();
}
```

converted to F#:

```
member this.Welcome (name : string, num_times : int) =
    this.ViewData.Add("Message", box ("Hello " + name))
    this.ViewData.Add("NumTimes", box num_times)

    this.View()
```